# Using database count rather than counting results in PHP mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

How to convert to use a database count?

```
function get_orders_count(){                                                                    
  global $mysqli;                                                                        
  $query ='                                                                                      
    SELECT                                                                                 
      a.order_id                                                                     
    FROM                                                                                   
      assignments a                                                                  
    WHERE                                                                                  
      client_id = '.$_SESSION['user']['ID'];                                         
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);                                                              
  return $result->num_rows;                                                                      
}
```

Comment: What are you asking? Is this not working?

Comment: @lampwins it seems inefficient

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COUNT` SQL function.

```
function get_orders_count(){                                                                    
  global $mysqli;                                                                        
  $query ='                                                                                      
    SELECT                                                                                 
      COUNT(a.order_id)                                                                     
    FROM                                                                                   
      assignments a                                                                  
    WHERE                                                                                  
      client_id = '.$_SESSION['user']['ID'];                                         
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);                                                              
  return $result->$result->fetch_row()[0];                                                                      
}
```

If `order_id` is the primary key use

```
COUNT(*)
```